# magento2: how to add store manager

Tags: magento2, admin, multistore

how to add store manager user in magento2 multi-store so that particular manager/user can view and/or manage own store related settings ?

```
Store name     |   Store admin 
Main store     |   Admin@MainStore
Store 1        |   Admin@Store1
Store 2        |   Admin@Store2
```

Only `Admin@MainStore` can change global settings where `Admin@Store1` and `Admin@Store2` would change settings related to their own stores `Store1` and `Store2` respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2 **Community**, this is not possible to manage ACL by store.

This is a feature avaiable in **EE** if i recall =/.